# How to write content on multiple pages with pdfbox in java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to extract all the content from a .txt file and then create a pdf file which will contain the exact content. The problem is that my program works only for 1 page content and I don't know how to make it work for multiple pages. This is what I've done so far:

```
public class Controller {

    private int margin = 20;
    private PDPage page = new PDPage();

public void createPDF(File file) {
    String content = readFileContent(file);
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    int fontSize = 10;
    int lineHeigh = 5;
    PDRectangle mediabox = page.findMediaBox();
    float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2 * margin;
    float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
    float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;

    try {
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        drawMultiLineText(content, startX, startY, width, page, contentStream, font, fontSize, lineHeigh);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void drawMultiLineText(String text, float x, float y, float allowedWidth, PDPage page,
                               PDPageContentStream contentStream, PDFont font, int fontSize, int lineHeight) throws IOException {

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    String myLine = "";

    // get all words from the text
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {

        if (!myLine.isEmpty()) {
            myLine += " ";
        }

        // test the width of the current line + the current word
        int size = (int) (fontSize * font.getStringWidth(myLine + word) / 1000);
        if (size > allowedWidth) {
            // if the line would be too long with the current word, add the line without the current word
            lines.add(myLine);

            // and start a new line with the current word
            myLine = word;
        } else {
            // if the current line + the current word would fit, add the current word to the line
            myLine += word;
        }
    }
    // add the rest to lines
    lines.add(myLine);
    for (String line : lines) {
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, y);
        contentStream.drawString(line);
        contentStream.endText();

        y -= lineHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to convert text to a PDF, use the TextToPDF command line utility. The source code is in the source code download of your PDFBox version. Your own code is very incomplete, it would not even work for one page, I see no save() and no .addPage() call, and you're not closing the content stream. So my own answer would just be to copy & paste the TextToPDF  source, not sure if I should do that :-)

Comment: As @TilmanHausherr pointed out, your code does not even work for a single page. But let's assume you were somewhat sloppy when posting your code here. In that case it is obvious what to do: You have to also provide an `allowedHeight` parameter to your `drawMultiLineText` method; then that method must check before drawing another line exceeds that height. If it does, it has to stop drawing lines and **either** create a new page and content stream to continue on that **or** return the unused text to the caller and let the caller do the page creation work.